# MaxPriorityQueue in JS runtime fromArray is not a function

Tags: javascript, queue

As per the supported runtime for different languages in https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-, I am using https://github.com/datastructures-js/priority-queue#fromarray as this is a function of the supported library.

However, when I use

```
const maxHeap = MaxPriorityQueue.fromArray(nums);
```

I get an error

```
Line 11 in solution.js
  const maxHeap = MaxPriorityQueue.fromArray(nums);
                                   ^
TypeError: MaxPriorityQueue.fromArray is not a function
    Line 11: Char 36 in solution.js (findKthLargest)
    Line 34: Char 19 in solution.js (Object.<anonymous>)
    Line 16: Char 8 in runner.js (Object.runner)
    Line 23: Char 26 in solution.js (Object.<anonymous>)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

This is in accordance with the example provided https://github.com/datastructures-js/priority-queue#js-3

Comment: What have you done so far to investigate the problem? Have you used the browser debugger to look at the `MaxPriorityQueue` object?

Comment: It is in the Leetcode JS run time. I tried multiple options considering the docs would be incorrect. Calling it as a function or using it as constructor too dont help. Its only alternative is to enqueue all items one by one which will be O(nlog(n)) instead of O(n)

Comment: OK but that does not answer my question.

Comment: Mentioned what I have done so far. Didn't try this in the browser debugger.

Comment: Well where are you trying it? In a browser? Node? Why would you not check the debugger or at least add some `console.log()` statements?

Comment: As mentioned in the comment, it is in the leetcode js run time. console.log just says it extends the PriorityQueue Class. Object.keys for it just shows `[ '_priority', '_heap' ]`. Of course I would have tried console.log before asking for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is kind of late to answer, but I'm going to answer anyway because I was facing the same issue.

The problem is that Leetcode uses version 4.1 of the library, and in this version, the `fromArray` doesn't exist yet.

Sadly, from what I looked up, there's no alternative to that method.

Doc: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@datastructures-js/priority-queue/v/4.1.0